# Bottom navigation bar item underline selected icon

Tags: flutter, dart

in-app bottom bar I want to add an underline for specifically selected icon. Is there any way for BottomNavigationBarItem or do I need to use a different widget?

[image]

```
class CustomAppBottomBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomAppBottomBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomAppBottomBar> createState() => _CustomAppBottomBarState();
}

class _CustomAppBottomBarState extends State<CustomAppBottomBar> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      showUnselectedLabels: true,
      showSelectedLabels: true,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      selectedItemColor: RJDriverColors.primary,
      unselectedItemColor: RJDriverColors.bottomBarSecondary,
      selectedFontSize: 12,
      unselectedFontSize: 12,
      currentIndex: _currentIndex,
      onTap: (value) {
        setState(() {
          _currentIndex = value;
        });
      },
```

Comment: Please check if this helps: https://fluttertutorial.in/bottom-navigation-bar-using-underline-in-flutter/

Comment: You could use `TabBar` since it already comes with the underline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using 'TabBar' and use `onTap` as `onChanged` since they are both of type `ValueChanged<int>`

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final TabController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = TabController(length: 4, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
        controller: controller,
        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
        labelColor: Colors.blue,
        onTap: (index) {},
        tabs: const [
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.menu_rounded)),
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.piano)),
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.car_rental_rounded)),
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.settings_rounded)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using **Tabbar** with **DefaultTabController** you can get your `desired` result. I'm sharing a reference code you can `customize` it as per your need.

```
 return  DefaultTabController(
          length: 4,
          child: Scaffold(
            body: TabBarView(
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: Text("1st Screen"),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text("2nd Screen"),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text("3rd Screen"),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text("4th Screen"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
              labelColor: Colors.red,
                tabs: [
              Tab(child: Icon(Icons.more_vert_sharp),),
              Tab(child: Icon(Icons.local_play_sharp),),
              Tab(child: Icon(Icons.directions_car),),
              Tab(child: Icon(Icons.home),),
            ]),
          ),
        );
```